# error: use of undeclared identifier 'GMSServices' [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"]; flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps

flutter ios error Users/slashglobal/Desktop/myMac/getx_zippyriders/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.m:8:6: error: **use of undeclared identifier 'GMSServices'** [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEy"];

issue Solved might be Helpfull

Answer (score 2):

Just go to: **ios\runner\AppDelegate.h** and Import `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`